# How to launch Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have downloaded Mono for Windows from [This](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) page. And installed it. Since I am very new to this program I even couldn't find how to launch it. All I can see in the start menu are those in the picture. So how can I launch this Mono software?

[image]

Comment: First use a basic google query, like "how to start mono on windows".  Take the first hit.  Ask a specific question after you've read through the Mono guide if you need more help.

Comment: @HansPassant I have searched. They all skip this part. They all assume I am seeing a launcher icon on Star Menu.

Comment: It is very, *very*, important that you mention that in your question.  If you don't tell us what you've read up so far then we don't know where to start.  That first Google hit tells you to start "Mono Command Prompt".  I see one in your screenshot.  It is very, *very* important that you tell us what happened when you clicked it.

Comment: Now I got your point. Thank you for clarification. I will edit my post according to my search history. I was just thinking of someone who had the same problem in the past. But since it is not a common case, your point is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mono** is a cross-platform implementation of .NET (which you definitely don't need if you are targeting windows)

**MonoDevelop** is an IDE (integrated development environment) that builds Mono/.NET applications.

You only installed Mono (the framework) and you don't "run" a framework. To get the IDE, go to [MonoDevlop](http://monodevelop.com/). Also, since you are on Windows, I would recommend using Visual Studio (Microsoft's .NET IDE) instead. The express editions are free, and all editions will compile to something Mono would run (you should probably target .NET 4 just to be safe). Many (including myself) consider it to be a far superior product.

Comment: Thank you that's illimunating.By the way MonodDEveloper you mean Xamarin Studio ? I have been using Visual Studio for a long time. I am using Windows but I need to create a C# application for our Computer laboratory which is full of Linux. I need to create this on windows and use it on linux. Shouldn't I use MonoDEvelop insted of Visual Studio to make the app cross platform when I am creating the app?

Comment: MonoDevelop and Xamarin studio are still (I'm pretty sure) different products. As far as development goes, I would still develop on VS (since it is SO much better than MonoDevelop) and test on my platform at the end like @jariq said.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by "launch this Mono software". Mono just provides the runtime environment capable of executing other .net applications. You won't get much benefit from launching mono alone (it is just a command line application) exactly as you won't get much benefit from launching java runtime standalone (which is also just a command line application). However you can use mono to execute .NET applications exactly as you can use java runtime to execute java applications but since you are using Windows you should already have .NET framework installed which does exactly what Mono does - provides the runtime environment for .NET applications.

Comment: Thakns for the insight. Now I get it a little more. Now this question arises. I am using Windows but I need to create C# application for our Computer laboratory which is full of Linux. I need to create this on windows and use it on linux. Shouldn't I use Mono when I am creating the app?

Comment: @Zgrknr Mono and .NET are fully compatible so it does not matter which one you use but there are [some things that are not fully implemented in Mono](http://mono-project.com/Compatibility). I usually use Visual Studio on Windows to develop my projects and from time to time I test my app on Linux and OSX with Mono. But you can also develop in Xamarin Studio on whichever platform you like the most.